# mysqli_prepare in PHP inserts nothing for emails

Tags: php, mysqli, insert, prepared-statement, procedural-programming

I'm converting several mysql statements over to procedural prepared statements in PHP and everything has been going fine until I tried to bind an email address to a mysqli_stmt_bind_param. I have used this website for years, but this is my first post because I can truly not find an answer to this issue.

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($rw_link, "INSERT INTO user (gid,name,email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $gpl_id, $gpl_displayName, $gpl_email);

$gpl_id="1111";
$gpl_displayName="Test Name";
$gpl_email="test@test.com";

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));
```

1 row is inserted. What is inserted is the id and name but the email is just a "0". I have seen other examples of people using emails here and i have literally copied the code and I am having the same issue.

Datatype is varchar(55)
Table: http://cl.ly/image/2r1H1k203G1U

If a number is inserted it updates the value..

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $gpl_id, $gpl_displayName, $gpl_email);

$gpl_id="1111";
$gpl_displayName="Test Name";
//$gpl_email="test@test.com";
$gpl_email="12345";

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

If the insert statement is not prepared, it inserts the email properly:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO user (gid,name,email) values ('" . $gpl_id . "','" . $gpl_displayName . "','" . $gpl_email . "')";
mysqli_query($rw_link,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($rw_link));
```

Comment: That chunk of code works fine for me. I get email inserted okay.

Comment: so what type is the `email` field? e.g. won't help to stuff a string into an int field.

Comment: I keep hoping its something that simple... Datatype is varchar(55)

Comment: which charset u using for `email` field?

Comment: export your table to a sql code, then show it to us...

Comment: it works good for me too...

Comment: Do you have proper `error_reporting` enabled? If not, do so _now._

Comment: Yes error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);